# T-SQL Trigger AFTER INSERT blocks update from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have an application which inserts to and updates a table using Entity Framework.
I have a function that handles both inserts and updates - receives the new/updated entity and handles it accordingly.

```
public int SubmitMyTable(MyTable myTable)
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext DBContext = new DataClassesDataContext(ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            MyTable updateMyTable = (from ag in DBContext.MyTables
                                             where ag.ID == myTable.ID
                                             select ag).SingleOrDefault();
            if (updateMyTable == null)
            {
                DBContext.MyTables.InsertOnSubmit(myTable);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    updateMyTable = (MyTable)CopyProperties(myTable, updateMyTable);
                }
                catch (ChangeConflictException cce)
                {
                    foreach (var conflict in DBContext.ChangeConflicts)
                    {
                        conflict.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepChanges);
                    }
                }
            }
            DBContext.SubmitChanges();
            return myTable.ID;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

For new inserts, I simply do `new MyTable()`, fill in the `NOT NULL` columns and send it to the above method. The `ID` column is an auto-incrementing `IDENTITY`.

For updates, I load an existing function by the ID column, update whatever fields need updating and send it off to the above method again.

Now, whenever a new row is inserted, or an existing row is updated, I want to update a sequence in the same database.

I have set a trigger for Update events like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MYCOUNTER]
ON [dbo].[MyTable]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR MYSEQUENCE
```

This works just fine for all update actions on the table. I am still missing Insert actions on that table. I have tried adding the Insert action on the "AFTER" line  like so:

```
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
```

as well as creating another trigger with the exact same syntax/contents except for its name and "INSERT" instead of "UPDATE" alongside the Update trigger.

Adding INSERT creates a problem where INSERT actions on the DB table using Entity Framework are successful. Meanwhile, **UPDATE action do nothing**!! The row stays the same as it was after the initial INSERT, I get no exception from the Entity Framework, but nothing happens!

I have verified that this is the problem - by removing the trigger for INSERT and everything goes back to normal. The moment I add it back, the problem returns...

Anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Comment: How do you assign new key values to new entities?

Comment: @GertArnold see the edited question - I added the calls to linq-to-sql